# jQuery Traverse to Closest Nested Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a better way to find a nested element within a parent element than what I have done here. I am wondering because if I decide to change the structure of the HTML, I'm not sure this solution will always be the best. In this example, I am trying to get the `entity-name`class element from the within the `col-sm-6` class element when you click on the button element.

```js
    $('.btn', '.row.character-select').on('click', event => {
      let entityName = $('.entity-name', $(event.currentTarget).closest('.card-body')).text();

      console.log(entityName);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row character-select d-none d-sm-flex mb-3 border-top border-bottom border-secondary">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 d-flex justify-content-around p-2 col-full-card">
        <div class="card game-card p-1">
          <img class="card-img-top entity-img" src="" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body p-0">
            <h5 class="card-title text-center m-0 pt-1 pb-2">
              <b class="entity-name">Bruce Willis</b>
            </h5>
            <hr class="mt-0">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col text-center">
                  <h5>
                    Attack:
                    <span class="entity-attack">2300</span>
                  </h5>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row mb-2">
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="progress" style="height: 25px;">
                    <div class="progress-bar bg-success text-dark" role="progressbar" style="width: 100%;" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0"
                      aria-valuemax="100">
                      <b class="entity-health">100</b>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row mt-1">
                <div class="col text-center">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary">Choose Player</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `$(event.currentTarget).closest('.card-body').find('.entity-name').text();`  is that what you are looking for? doing this will assure you get the text on entity-name if both the button and the entity-name are inside the card-body

Comment: @animake Basically I'm looking to see if there is some kind of way of just using `closest()` and it finds the closest `entity-name`. It would need to traverse up the parents, but then also inside on them to find the closest `entity-name`

Comment: you can't do that using only `closest`. `entity-name` must be the button's parent to do that

Comment: @animake Yea. I guess I will just need to make my own function that looks through the children in each parent till it finds it.

Comment: `.find` does that if you just give `.closest` the absolute parent you're trying to use. in your case `.row.character-select` i guess

Comment: I just gave an answer summing up your problem @Philosec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there **is** a way. But you might not like it. I'm not sure I do!

`let entityName = $(event.currentTarget).closest($('*').has('.entity-name')).find('.entity-name').text();`

This finds all elements that have a `.entity-name` descendent, and looks for the `.closest()` of those, and then searches down again for the actual `.entity-name` element.

It removes the need for the `.col-sm-6` or `.card-body` reference.

https://jsfiddle.net/f04nxten/5/

Comment: I tried the code and it works well. If I may ask, why do you not like it?

Comment: @Raith but he will probably need an entity-name per card, in this case this doesn't work

Comment: @animake Actually this is working per card. I spawn 4 cards and with this code it grabs each of their names correctly.

Comment: The jsfiddle shows that this does work when the page has multiple cards. I don't like it because I don't know how efficient it is. And anything with $('*') has got to be a bad code smell :(

Comment: I changed the answer to accept this one. It seems to fit exactly what I was trying to do.

Comment: If this were a solution for myself then I would stick to your original query as its performance is more predictable. But if you *really* want to get rid of one of your HTML structure dependencies, then that's your call... :)

Answer (score 0):

Traversing the tree will always require that you have some reference points, and these will always risk being broken by changes to your HTML.

In your example you state that you wish to find the `entity-name` class element within the `col-sm-6` class element that contains the clicked button. However, your JQuery then uses the `card-body` class element as a reference point!

You currently require that the clicked button and the `entity-name` class element will exist within the same `card-body`. Your own example is as good as this can get other than by using `.closest('.col-sm-6')` which better reflects your question.

You are right that this is easily broken, so you should pick your references carefully. It sounds to me that `card-body` is already a safer bet than `col-sm-6`. You will need to change your selector if you change your HTML, but you will not find a selector that lets you navigate up then down again without being dependent on some reference points.

Comment: Thanks! This explains it very well. It felt like I had the best solution I could get, just wanted to be sure.